# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error on running the webapp on localhost

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a webapp on Chrome. My index.html gets loaded, however the googleapis and angular js files are not getting imported and on inspecting the error is:

GET https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

All the local js files are getting loaded, however all cdnjs files and angular js files are not getting loaded. I tried setting nameserver to 8.8.8.8, however the error doesnot get away. Is it some certificate issue? I am running the webapp from localhost. There are other URLS importing angular scripts that are also giving the same error.

Comment: It's a DNS error. Might have to do with firewall configurations of your router

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an error in DNS resolution, which is not programming.

Answer (score 1):

To understand this error you have to understand how domain names work.

When your computer goes looking for say "www.cloudfare.com", it doesn't know where that is, so it asks a "DNS server" what the corresponding IP address is for that domain.  This is essentially the same idea as an old phone book: you give the DNS servers a name, and you get back a number that you (or at least your computer) can actually use.

In this case, the error you're seeing indicates your computer wasn't able to resolve https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com and find an IP address for it.  Most likely this has something to do with your local network.  For instance, you might have configured your router to block that domain, or you might have added entry to your `/etc/hosts` file for that domain, with an invalid IP address.

Unfortunately the ultimate solution depends heavily on your local circumstances: essentially you just have to fix whatever is getting in the way of your computer resolving that domain.

Comment: I  did make the changes related to dns as in by including the nameserver  8.8.8.8, but yet see the same error. And there is one more thing which I dont understand- I am able to open google.com from Chrome, but when I am trying to include the js files by including them in the index. html file and running it from localhost, google.com is unreachable. Not sure what exactly is happening? I googled and saw  a couple of posts where one cant make a https call from local host for some certificate issue. Is it something related?

Comment: Perhaps check your firewall settings (or try disabling any firewalls you have temporarily to see if that helps.  Again, it's really hard to say as it could be anything on your computer, or on the network in-between that's to blame ... although the fact that the URLs work in Chrome suggests strongly that it's something configured on your computer.